# "Count maximum number of thieves that can be caught" question should be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, broken-code

The following question was closed as off-topic:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176469/count-maximum-number-of-thieves-that-can-be-caught

The code seems complete to me and the question is complete and clear. Moreover, I have started to code an answer.

Answer (score 7):

The question says:

> Out of 24 test-cases 18 passed, the rest got the wrong answer.
>   If the approach is wrong I would like to know the correct answer.

As per the [Help Center rules](/help/on-topic), broken code is off-topic, especially if the question asks for help with troubleshooting or for a debugged solution.  For a discussion of what constitutes "broken", see: [What exactly does it mean for code to be "Working Code"?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2535)

If the online judge says that the code gives wrong answers, then we should assume that the code is broken, unless the author includes extraordinary evidence to the contrary.

Comment: I'm not sure any such evidence exists.... it's important to point out the difference between "wrong answer" and "time limit exceeded" here though.